# JXL + POI : incompatibility

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl, jexcelapi, poi-hssf

Im first using JXL to modify one xls file created by POI. After that I will try to read that file with POI. In the moment of POIFSFileSystem creation

```
 poFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(input);
```

Im getting the exception

```
 java.io.IOException: block[ 907 ] already removed - does your POIFS have circular or duplicate block references?
```

Is this a compatibility problem between those 2 libraries or something else?
Im using POI ver 3.6 and latest version of JXL.

Thanks

Comment: POI 3.6 is a little old, have you tried with the latest version? Also, can you try opening with NPOIFSFileSystem instead of the older POIFSFileSystem to see if it helps?

Comment: i tried also with 3.8 but i have the same problem.. I will try right now with NPOIFSFileSystem

Comment: yes changing POIFSFileSystem  to NPOIFSFileSystem solved my problem. thanks

Answer (score 1):

changing POIFSFileSystem to NPOIFSFileSystem solved my problem.